# Installing CentOS and Kali as dual boot?

Tags: centos, kali-linux

I'm going to install a machine with both CentOS and Kali. What are the steps to follow? Which should I install first CentOS or Kali?

The issue I tried to run Kali as virtual machine however, it just failed to start. I also tried running via USB, but it runs and then each time it loses all my previous settings. Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The issue I tried to run Kali as virtual machine however, it just failed to start. I also tried running via USB, but it runs and then each time it loses all my previous settings. Please advise.

In this case i would install Kali first and then CentOS.

Please note that if you run Kali on a USB, you run in **live mode**, it means that every time you reboot the system you will lose all your changes.

If you want to persist Kali on your hard disk you must download and ISO image and follow [this](http://docs.kali.org/installation/kali-linux-hard-disk-install) instructions. 
But at step 6 you must create two different partitions (this is by selecting the 'Manual' option).

Then you should download and install Centos (it will automatically create a GRUB menu, and you should be able to select which systems start at start-up).

Regards!

Comment: Just want to add that it's possible to have _persistence_ on a live USB pendrive. Certainly not full-proof but [possible](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)...

Comment: Indeed, but isn't the default configuration.

Comment: @gryphes yes that is my problem say for instance I am need to open vas and using live mode I have to set it up each time kind of difficult. Ok I have the iso downloaded ready and its on my usb. Can I now start to install from my usb ?

Comment: @biz14, yes, it's the same processes. Check out the link on my post, under the paragraph **Preparing for the Installation**

Comment: @gryphes yes I am checking it let me do a test and update accordingly for the benefit of rest.

Comment: @gryphes just to update you I had one machine with Centos install. So then I tried to install kali and I choose manual partition I saw first it say 1st primary 542.3 mb ext4 , 2nd primary 52.4 mv ext4, 3rd primary 8..46gb swap. So this was the centos files. Then there was ample space I had to manually create each different parition I just fixed each 50gb for / /home /usr /var /temp /usr/local /opt /srv /boot and then only it works. Why my kali partition are labelled logical and not primary ?

Comment: Just to add further infact kali also got grub where it could detect centos and ask for the option.

Answer (score -1):

Not to discourage your decision, but I would consider how you plan to utilize this system once it's configured.  The nature of these two operating systems is very different, almost opposite in some regards.  Much of what can be done with Kali can be done in Cent as well.  You may not need both unless the exercise is to weigh them against each other.